# ExpressJS with Pug - Tailwind properties not being applied

Tags: express, pug, tailwind-css

I'm using Express/Node with Pug as the view template. Attempting to use Tailwind for styling, but have been unable to get Tailwind to modify my CSS based on the classnames added in the Pug files.  Has anyone run into this before?

[image]

Here is the Pug file where I'm attempting to modify how "Testing tailwind" will display. However, it loads with black plain text.

[image]

I was able to populate my style.css file with the tailwind boilerplate base, components, and utilities. If I style the class name in styles.css it works, so the file is linked correctly...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must add `pug` in the content field of `tailwind.config.js` as below:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./**/*.pug"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: Enter the static path in app.js like this:

Comment: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/styles")));

Comment: Edit your answer to add information or code. Then delete these comments.

Comment: Write it in tailwind.config.js

Comment: I was missing adding `pug` in the `content:[...]` field of `tailwind.config.js`. This helped

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Tailwind was not render. In [this article](https://daily.dev/blog/how-to-use-tailwindcss-with-node-js-express-and-pug) and [this video](https://youtu.be/YnvH-ouX_y4) show how to do it.

You must install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer postcss-cli

```
npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer postcss-cli
```

Create postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports =
{
    plugins:
    {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
}
```

and tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports =
{
    content:
    [
        './views/*.{pug, html}',
    ],
    theme:
    {
        extend:
        {

        },
    },
    plugins:
    [

    ],
}
```

And public/styles/tailwind.css css file within

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

To package.json add script

```json
"tailwind:build": "postcss public/styles/tailwind.css -o public/styles/style.css",
```

And now you can build tailwind for your pug templates or some other html files. Just run `npm run tailwind:build` and open your host

But for don't running again and again this script you can watching for files with this script

```json
"tailwind:watch": "postcss public/styles/tailwind.css -w -o public/styles/style.css"
```

Just run `npm run tailwind:watch` and your css file will be updating on change tailwind.css file

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem. I was following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnvH-ouX_y4) and at the end, tailwind didn't seem to work at all.

After looking at [document](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html), I tried a new approach and it worked:


**Instead of:**

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0")
    title Node.js with TailwindCSS, Express and Pug
    // Injecting css file as the tutorial
    link(href="./styles/style.css", rel="stylesheet")
  body
    h1 Hello world!
    p My starter template
```

**Try this:**

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0")
    title Node.js with TailwindCSS, Express and Pug
// Follow the document
    style 
      include ../public/styles/styles.css
```

This worked out for me, I hope this helps some of you.
Happy coding!